# HTC ONE x HDMI fixed at portrait during rotation

Tags: htc-one-x, hdmi, auto-rotation

I have a microUSB - HDMI adapter bought off of ebay, and an international Quad core HTC ONE X.

I tried connecting the adapter (power and signal cables were both attached) but the orientation is fixed to portrait. If I set the autorotation on the mobile to `on`, and rotate the landscape, the input on the HDTV is rotated as well but the picture stays within the portrait viewing area. So, I have huge black bars all around the picture.

i'm running CyanogenMod, on the latest nightly.

Comment: Are you using the default image viewer, or a specific app?

Comment: It's quite possible that the output is fixed to what the adapter is capable of displaying. Who knows what the specs are if you bought it off ebay, do you know for a fact what resolutions are supported?